# Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 2 in

Tags: php, mysql, restrict

I am trying to make it so I can restrict the "staff panel" to users with there "member_level" at "3" so others get redirected to the account_page.php but I am currently getting a error which only cropped up 1hr ago, this came out of nowhere I didn't change anything it just came up.

This is the code for the staff panel:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
mysql_connect('localhost', 'u1908470_cms', 'BeingX1309X')or die("Error: ".mysqlerror());
mysql_select_db('u1908470_cms'); 

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT 'member_level' FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($_SESSION['user']['username'])."'");
$query2 = mysql_result($query1,0,'member_level') or die(mysql_error());

switch ($query2)
{
case 3: 
  {
  echo "<p>Now Logged into Staff Panel!</p>";

  }
  break;

case 2:
  {
  header("location: http://www.cookiedenied.com/account_page.php"); 
  }
  break;

case 1:
  {
  header("location: http://www.cookiedenied.com/account_page.php"); 
  }
  break;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Escape field and table names properly**

Instead of

```
    SELECT 'member_level', ....
```

...please use...

```
    SELECT `member_level`, ....
```

**Validate your Query.**

Rewrite your code like this:

```
$SQL = "SELECT `member_level`
    FROM `users` 
    WHERE `username` = '" 
    . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']['username'])
    . "'";

$MyQ = mysql_query($SQL);
$MyR = mysql_result($MyQ,0,'member_level') or die(mysql_error());
```

...and `var_dump($SQL);` to see if your statement is valid. Check it while executing it with another MySQL Tool (Workbench, phpMyAdmin, SQLyog or whatever) to see if it generates any results. Maybe the `$_SESSION` variable isn't set up properly or something similar, you'll find out this way.

**Please use MySQLi or PDO instead.**

From the manual:

> Use of the mysql extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or
>   PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

**Reformat your `switch`-Block.**

Not related to your question, but your `switch`-Block looks overly complicated to archieve something way easier. Try this:

```
switch ($query2) {
    case 3: 
        echo "<p>Now Logged into Staff Panel!</p>";
        break;
    default:
        header("location: http://www.cookiedenied.com/account_page.php"); 
}
```

Comment: Done all that the error doesn't change except on the line, I have put the var_dump($SQL); under $MyQ = mysql_query($SQL);
$MyR = mysql_result($MyQ,0,'member_level') or die(mysql_error()); would that work?

Comment: Well, it will show you the SQL statement, then you can see if it works or not!

Comment: As said to Abishkek above: fair answer and worth a +1, but why not teach him how to handle errors properly instead? If he does the fix you describe, he still has a broken program.

Comment: @Pekka Very true, but concluding from the code first some basics have to be taught before delving into error handling and such.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$R = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
$query2 = $R["member_level"]
```

But may be you should check that your query returns at least 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to avoid mysql_query. This is getting obsolete and make a habit of using PDO.

In your query you have surrounded the tablename with quotes. Remove the quotes and try.

Change the code. And replace with the below code.

```
<?php
ob_start();
try {

      $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u1908470_cms', 'u1908470_cms','BeingX1309X');

} catch (PDOException $e) {

      print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
      die();

}

$username = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
$statement = $pdo->prepare("select `member_level` from `users` where username = :username");
$statement->execute(array(':username' => $username));
$row = $statement->fetch();

$member_level = $row['member_level'];
switch ($member_level)
{
    case 3: {
        echo "<p>Now Logged into Staff Panel!</p>";
        break;
    }
    default:{

        header("location: http://www.cookiedenied.com/account_page.php"); 
        break;
    }
}
```

You can actually remove the switch statement and just put if-else condition.

```
if($member_level == 3) {

  echo "<p>Now Logged into Staff Panel!</p>";

}else{

  header("location: http://www.cookiedenied.com/account_page.php"); 

}
?>
```

Comment: Fair answer, but why not teach him how to handle errors properly instead? If he does the fix you describe, he still has a broken program.

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately made no difference.

Comment: You forgot to remove the last `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Tried this also and removed the `mysql_real_escape_string` as Pekka said and I got the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in` which means its for this line `$statement = $db->prepare("select `member_level` from `users` where username = :username");`

Comment: Thanks @Pekka for noticing. I have added a try catch block. Update your code with that. Check if you get any errors.

Comment: Thanks, Done that I get the same error for the same line of code ` $statement = $db->prepare("select `member_level` from `users` where username = :username"); `

Comment: Thanks it works as far as I can tell, but it doesn't stop redirecting when a user has the member_level of 3, how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: You can just remove the switch statement and use if-else condition.

Comment: Having a few problems with it just letting me through now, even used your if-else conditions and it keeps using the else redirecting when it should in fact be letting me stay.

Comment: Hmmm. try it this way - if(trim($member_level) == 3)

Comment: Tried the `if(trim($member_level) == 3)` still the same redirecting.

Comment: If still it doesnt work use var_dump($member_level) to anaylyze the variable. when you do this comment the header part so that it doesnt redirect.

Comment: Are you sure you have member_level of value 3 in your database ?

Comment: Tried using `var_dump($member_level);` posted NULL on the page and I am definitely sure I have it in, I have it in my database this is its details: 7 member_level varchar(4) utf8_bin No 1

Comment: I'm using the session for the username.

Answer (score 0):

Why you have `'` around `table name` in your query, it might be back tick

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT `member_level` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($_SESSION['user']['username'])."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Use `or die(mysql_error());` to check error in your query.